# Access 2010 report invoice total

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to do a report invoice and need to give a total cost for each customer invoice, but so far all I am getting is the microsoft #error!

[image: Picture of the output produced, including the error]

The formular I am using at present is:

```
 =Sum([qry5InvoiceCalculated]![OrderTotal(AU)])
```

I have tried other formulas, but keep getting the same #error!
What am I doing wrong, or is the a formula that I have not tried yet?

Here is the [file](http://www.pkwebdesigns.com.au/Report.zip), if you would like to take a look at it to see what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `=Sum([OrderTotal(AU)])`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that!

Comment: But @Andre did show the correct expression. Maybe you will have to _rename_ the sum control?

Comment: =Sum([OrderTotal(AU)]) produces the #error! Is there some setting in properties perhaps, that I need to set, or unset?

Comment: The report relies on query qry5InvoiceCalculated, which has OrderTotal(AU) as a calculated field. Would this be the problem?

Comment: Rename the control that holds the `OrderTotal(AU)` value to something else, preferably something without special characters and try to use Sum on that.

Comment: I did try that, a couple of times. In the report and also the query, but nothing is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else stuck on this. The following does what I needed!

When creating the grouping, ensure that you select "with a footer section!"

[image: Ensure that you select "with a footer section!"]

There is possibly a better way to achieve the end goal, but this works!

Answer (score 1):

I opened your file. The problem is: your report layout is wrong.

Your `Sum()` formula is in the page footer - that cannot work, because it is pretty much random how many records will be on one page.

Move it into the report footer, and it works without changes.

But it's still wrong, because you have multiple customers in your query. So you need to add a [**grouping**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-6a58e9ab-9f74-4689-83b6-c63cddb2c7f9) by customer id. Then move everything from the page header to the group header, and the `Sum()` to the group footer.

Comment: Tried that, it gave me a Cust ID header, but no footer?

Comment: OK, seems I finally have what I needed. I had to go to the options drop down list when adding the group and tell it to also include a footer!

Comment: If you put anything in the report footer, it only appears on the very last page!

Comment: @user3633383: Yes, you need to tell it to add a group footer. And yes, the report footer (by definition) appears only on the last page. A sum in there makes sense if your report is opened for one customer only, but not for your case. But a sum in the page footer never makes sense (and doesn't work).